# Eloquent relationship structure for league app

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I've been working on an Angular app with a Laravel rest API and have realised my relationships aren't quite as they should be.

I have 3 entities - ***seasons***, ***divisions*** and ***teams***.

**Season:**

A season has many divisions, and many teams.

**Division:**

A division belongs to many seasons, and has many teams.

**Team:**

A team belongs to many divisions, and belongs to many seasons.

This is because a division may not be used for every season, and a team may change divisions each season, or may not play in all seasons.

I'm struggling to understand how to implement the relationship logic.

For example, I'd like to get divisions for a season and the teams present in that division for that particular season, be it the current one or when the user is viewing an old season.

Here's what I've got at the moment:

**Season model**

```
class Season extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $hidden = ['pivot'];


    /**
     * Return divisions for this season
     *
     * @return BelongsToMany
     */
    public function divisions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Division');
    }

    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team');
    }

}
```

**Division Model**

```
class Division extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function matches()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Fixture');
    }

    public function seasons()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Season');
    }

    public function teams() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Team');
    }

}
```

**Team Model**

```
class Team extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $hidden = ['pivot'];

    public function division() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Division');
        // should be belongsToMany
    }

    public function seasons()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Season')->select('season_id');
    }
}
```

With the following tables:

- seasons
- divisions
- teams
- division_season
- season_team

But this doesn't enable me to have a team belonging to a different division per season.

If I change the `division()` method on the team model to be `divisions()` and with a `belongsToMany()` and have a new table - division_team (is this the right approach?) how would I then query all teams by their division on a per season basis?

Eg:

```
Get all divisions and their teams by season id
```

Bearing in mind teams have the potential to change divisions each season.

**EDIT**

As per answer from Thomas Van Der Veen's answer below, I have added a table division_season_team and used the relations in his answer.

Trying to get divisions with their teams based on a season id though is proving difficult - the below returns the correct divisions, but the teams aren't necessarily part of the current season!

**DivisionsController**

```
if ($request->query('seasonId')) {
    $seasonId = $request->query('seasonId');
    return $this->respond(new DivisionCollection(Division::with('teams')->whereHas(
     'seasons', function($q) use ($seasonId) {
         $q->where('season_id', '=', $seasonId);
        })->get()
    ));
}
```

Comment: @kerbholz apparently HasManyThrough doesn't work with many to many relationships

Comment: I suggest many to many relationships as this would avoid so much of your confusion

Comment: @AthulRaj I am using many to many relationships - see all code provided above plus the edit I made - where are you seeing anything to do with non many to many relationships?

Comment: @DJC I think you need to use [Many To Many (Polymorphic) Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations).

Comment: Yes I still see non many to many relationships. In division model there are two hasMany relations. you can also change that to many to many. If all thes models are many to many related and having pivot tables. I believe everything will work fine in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just don't use the correct query. Your query should be:

```
if ($seasonId = $request->input('seasonId')) {
    $season = Season::findOrFail($seasonId);

    $divisionIdsQuery = $season->divisions()
        ->select('divisions.id')
        ->groupBy('divisions.id')
        ->getQuery(); // can't just ->get(), because MYSQL FULL GROUP BY.

    $divisions = Division::whereIn('id', $divisionIdsQuery)
        ->with(['teams' => function ($query) use ($season) {
            $query->where('season_id', $season->id);
        }])
        ->get();

    return $this->respond(new DivisionCollection($divisions));
}
```

Comment: Hi this is close, though for every team in a given division, it returns the division and it's teams that number of times. Eg Pool A has 5 teams, your code returns Pool A and the correct teams, but it does so 5 separate times

Comment: @DJC Sorry, I can't understand what you want. Could you edit your question and provide us an example results that you want?

Comment: Sorry no, instead of receiving pool_a and it's teams for that season once (which is what I want), I receive that same result repeated for x number of times - x being the number of teams in that division for that season. Which makes sense since for each team in division_season_team a new row is inserted which includes the division_id, so I get the division and its teams for every row.

Comment: Oh ok, I see. Let me try.

Answer (score 3):

By reading your desired outcome a suggestion would be to create a single table that holds al those three relationships.

```
season_division_team // Or whatever you want to call it.
id
season_id
division_id
team_id
```

This allows you to easily create and update relations. All models can belong to many others.

Relations you now can have are:

```php
// Season
public function divisions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Division::class, 'season_division_team');
}

public function teams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, 'season_division_team');
}

// Division
public function seasons()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Season::class, 'season_division_team');
}

public function teams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, 'season_division_team');
}

// Team
public function seasons()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Season::class, 'season_division_team');
}

public function divisions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Division::class, 'season_division_team');
}
```

Comment: This looks promising - but what would the query / relationship method be to obtain all divisions and their respective teams from a specific season? I guess I also wouldn't need the division_season or season_team tables any longer?

Comment: @DJC Indeed you do not need the old tables any more. There are multiple ways to retrieve the result you want. It only depends in what form. You can (lazy) eager load the relations on the Season by using the  [`with`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) or [`load`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) methods. Or you could use the [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) to retrieve the related models.

Comment: Apologies for the delay here - I have added an edit with the additions you suggested, however as explained it isn't quite right!

Answer (score 0):

After read your edit I think that you can get this with a join inside the teams `with`.

Tables:

```
seasons
```

```
divisions
```

```
teams
```

```
season_divisions_teams
  - season_id
  - division_id
  - team_id
```

In your controller:

```
if ($request->query('seasonId')) {
    $seasonId = $request->query('seasonId');

    $result = Division::with(['teams' => function (Builder $query) use ($seasonId) {
        $query->select(["teams.*"]);
        $query->join('season_divisions_teams', 'season_divisions_teams.team_id', '=', 'teams.id');
        $query->where('season_divisions_teams.season_id', '=', $seasonId);
    }])
    ->whereHas('seasons', function(Builder $query) use ($seasonId) {
        $query->where('season_id', '=', $seasonId);
    })->get();

    return $this->respond(new DivisionCollection($result));
}
```

Explanation:

Like we are calling the relation between `divisions` and `teams` when we calling `with('teams')`, the teams that isn't in that division are excluded. After, we use a join between `teams` and `season_divisions_teams` to get the information about what teams are in the seasons, and we use a `where` to filter them by season id.

Comment: Hi thanks for this - though I get an error - Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'season_divisions_teams'